# updating last 2 char in varshar

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to make this update

```
update c_order set documentno = 'OV1036477' where documentno = 'OV1036503';
update c_order set documentno = 'OV1036476' where documentno = 'OV1036502';
```

....etc

for all this documentNo's (this documentNo are ordered `[503 - 483]`)

OV1036503

OV1036502

OV1036501

OV1036500

OV1036499

OV1036498

OV1036497

OV1036496

OV1036495

OV1036494

OV1036493

OV1036492

OV1036491

OV1036490

OV1036489

OV1036488

OV1036487

OV1036486

OV1036485

OV1036484

OV1036483

Question : how can i do this with one update ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you need one update?  If you have an index on `documentno`, then multiple updates would be reasonable.  If you wrap them in a single transaction (which they are by default), then they all take effect at the same time, when you commit the transaction.

Comment: i have this liste of 22 lines,  and an other liste of 28 lines, for 50 update , i will take a time to copy plaste them, i dont want to this, i want a simple update recursive may be if it's possible

Comment: What is a rule to update OV1036477,OV1036476 data.

Comment: i got an answer of this , you can check it , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this

```
update c_order set documentno = 'OV'||( to_number(substr(documentno,3))-26)
where documentno in ( 'OV1036503','OV1036502');
```

Comment: it's exactly what i want , thanks Ersin Gülbahar, i have confirmed your response

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to update all your rows :

```
UPDATE c_order SET documentno = 'OV' + CAST( RIGHT(documentno,7) - 26 AS 
VARCHAR)  

If you need WHERE Clause means :

UPDATE c_order SET documentno = 'OV' + CAST( RIGHT(documentno,7) - 26 AS  
VARCHAR) 
--WHERE Condition
```

Answer (score 1):

could you elaborate a little more so we could do a better suited answer?

There is some correspondence in the substitution? Like you want to change every end to -x value or there is a logic behind the process?

Anyway i guess something like this would do the trick:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited

declare
 type numListType is table of number;
 numList numListType;
 numList2 numListType;
begin
numList := numListType(
 503, 502, 501, 500, 499, 498, 497, 496, 495, 494, 493, 492, 491, 490, 489, 488, 487, 486, 485, 484, 483
);
numList2 := numListType(
 477, 476, 475, 474, 473, 472, 471, 470, 469, 468, 467, 466, 465, 464, 463, 462, 461, 460, 459, 458, 457
);
for i in numList.FIRST..numList.LAST loop
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update c_order set documentno = ''OV1036'|| 
                  numList2(i) || ''' where documentno = ''OV1036'|| numList(i)||'''';
end loop;
end;
/
```